# Python library for GPS trajectory pre-processing?

Tags: python, gps

I'd like to know if there is any implemented python library for GPS trajectory pre-processing such as compression, smoothing, filtering, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment, a *Kalman filter* is the usual choice for estimating position and velocity from noisy sensor readings.

Here's what Wikipedia has to say on the topic (emphasis mine:)

> The Kalman filter is an algorithm, commonly used since the 1960s for
>   improving vehicle navigation (among other applications, although
>   aerospace is typical), that yields an **optimized estimate** of the
>   system's state (e.g. **position and velocity**). The algorithm works
>   recursively **in real time on streams of noisy input observation data**
>   (typically, sensor measurements) and filters out errors using a
>   least-squares curve-fit optimized with a mathematical prediction of
>   the future state generated through a modeling of the system's physical
>   characteristics.

The Kalman filter is the basic version; there's also the *extended Kalman filter* and *unscented Kalman filter* (though my control systems lecturer never got around to telling us what those were actually used for.)

@stark has provided a link to an implementation of the Kalman filter in Python (not sure of the quality.) You may be able to find others, or roll your own with `scipy`.

Comment: I am familiar with common algorithms for compression and filtering. I just want to know if there are python library for it out there. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not GPS-specific, but [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/) has general statistics and scientific algorithms.  For example, if you want to make a best-fit line to a series of points, you would run a linear regression on the data.

Comment: Further to that, I believe a Kalman filter may be an appropriate signals processing algorithm to implement.

Comment: Great suggestion!
http://ascratchpad.blogspot.com/2010/03/kalman-filter-in-python.html

Comment: I am aware of numpy and scipy. Just looking for a library more specific to GPS processing.